# C # windows form I have created 20 textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

Good evening. In C # windows form I have created 20 textboxes which have the same numeric data.
In the code I have entered an error message, which says accept only numeric data.
This is the code:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]+$") == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C'è un campo con caratere non valido. E' richiesto solo numeri.");
        }
```

My problem is, to avoid writing the code 20 times for each textbox, is there a way to simplify the work?

Comment: Put the text boxes in a `List` and loop over it.

Comment: ....pass the text as a parameter?

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it, give an example? pass the text as a parameter? yes

Comment: Try a web search for "windows forms numeric text box"

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply disallow non-numeric values by using a NumericUpDown control or a custom NumericUpDown which has no spinners and has a property `AsInteger` for int.

```
public class SpecialNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{

        public SpecialNumericUpDown()
        {
            Controls[0].Hide();
            TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            // optionally set min and max values here or in the property window
        }
        protected override void OnTextBoxResize(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controls[1].Width = Width - 4;
        }
    
        [Browsable(false)] public int AsInteger => (int)Value;
    
        public delegate void TriggerDelegate();
    
        public event TriggerDelegate TriggerEvent;
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Return))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    
                TriggerEvent?.Invoke();
    
                return;
            }
    
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    
    }
```